# I can't change the 'style.left' property of a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are no errors when ran.

```
var P1 = document.getElementById("P1");

P1.style.left = "50%";
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. And why are you running an infinite loop every 5 milliseconds?

Comment: why do you think that you do not change the style? How do you tell? What should/does/doesn't happen? what other styles get applied to this node?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) if you are going to use the `left` property.

```js
var P1 = document.getElementById("P1");
var pct = 1;

function loop() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    P1.style.left = ++pct + "%";
    loop();
  }, 500)
}
loop();
```

```css
#P1 {
  background: black;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id=P1></div>
```